# AvalancheImagineBundle not creating thumbnail images?

Tags: php, symfony

I installed AvalancheImagineBundle for Symfony 2.0.

Everything wen't fine except the fact that it doesnt' generate thumbnail images after this line;

```
<img  src="{{  asset('uploads/apartments/4ef4be0edef4a.jpg') | apply_filter('my_thumb') }}" />
```

The image is there. I tried cutting out the apply_filter and the image gets shown.

The config is set fine aswell - I followed the basic instructions on the git page.

But the thumbnail doesnt appear in media/cache after page load. I have the folder structure there.

What could be the issue?

Comment: What does the server say, if you open the image directly from browser? Make sure to grab the proper link from a rendered page (where the image does not appear).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came across an issue where the thumbnail wasn't being created. You may have a similar problem.

**Background / Problem**

My images were not being saved and no thumbnail was being displayed.

This was because latest version on AvalancheImagineBundle is not compatible with the Symfony2 Standard Edition available from symfony.com.

The **[latest commit](https://github.com/avalanche123/AvalancheImagineBundle/commit/2ab28a25d323b9a596b3a3fbf8c4c92b9780b5c6)** changes some of the using statements. You can see if this is your problem by navigating to the image that is being displayed (in my case this was /uploads/media/4efc8d3e5c37d.png). Once there, if you get an error talking about 'Filesystem' do the following:

**Solution**

Instead of updating symfony2 I chose to use the version of AvalancheImagineBundle just before the latest commit. **[Find it here](https://github.com/avalanche123/AvalancheImagineBundle/tree/72a6d86bcaa3e498f3cf5e8d42ddf16fb3084d78)**. Of course, you could alternatively update symfony2.

Answer (score 3):

Remove the Assetic call..

Just pass the the image url to the apply_filter function..

Images are cached by ImagineBundle. you dont need asset() here.

Comment: Didn't fix the issue. Also, I must mention - I tried using ImagineBundle instead and it also doesn't work for me. Perhaps it's not usage / installation issue, it's something else.

Comment: This did it for me, everything worked fine locally however when uploading the project to a subdirectory online all the images broke, removing the assetic call fixed it.

Comment: seens okay with the new assetic update (2.3.1 and symfony 2.7.6), it seems that @user2019515 solutions workked for me ...

Answer (score 2):

try using

```
<img  src="{{  asset('../uploads/apartments/4ef4be0edef4a.jpg') | apply_filter('my_thumb') }}" />
```

note the ../ in the path, this worked for me when I had the same issue, avalanche seems to need a relative url